# Query is too high for Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, pivot, query-optimization, ms-access-2013

I need to optimize the following query. I know this is not the way to achieve this.

Query

```
 SELECT 'A1' AS Location , A1 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A2' AS Location , A2 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A3' AS Location , A3 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A4' AS Location , A4 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A5' AS Location , A5 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A6' AS Location , A6 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A7' AS Location , A7 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A8' AS Location , A8 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A9' AS Location , A9 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A10' AS Location , A10 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A11' AS Location , A11 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A12' AS Location , A12 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A13' AS Location , A13 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A14' AS Location , A14 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'A15' AS Location , A15 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B1' AS Location , B1 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B2' AS Location , B2 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B3' AS Location , B3 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B4' AS Location , B4 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B5' AS Location , B5 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B6' AS Location , B6 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B7' AS Location , B7 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B8' AS Location , B8 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B9' AS Location , B9 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B10' AS Location , B10 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B11' AS Location , B11 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B12' AS Location , B12 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B13' AS Location , B13 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B14' AS Location , B14 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'B15' AS Location , B15 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C1' AS Location , C1 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C2' AS Location , C2 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C3' AS Location , C3 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C4' AS Location , C4 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C5' AS Location , C5 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C6' AS Location , C6 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C7' AS Location , C7 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C8' AS Location , C8 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C9' AS Location , C9 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C10' AS Location , C10 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C11' AS Location , C11 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C12' AS Location , C12 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C13' AS Location , C13 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C14' AS Location , C14 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'C15' AS Location , C15 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D1' AS Location , D1 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D2' AS Location , D2 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D3' AS Location , D3 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D4' AS Location , D4 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D5' AS Location , D5 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D6' AS Location , D6 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D7' AS Location , D7 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D8' AS Location , D8 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D9' AS Location , D9 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D10' AS Location , D10 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D11' AS Location , D11 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D12' AS Location , D12 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D13' AS Location , D13 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D14' AS Location , D14 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'D15' AS Location , D15 AS Qty FROM Inventory where PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1
```

TAble structure is

```
Partnumber  Version Quantity A1 A2......A15 B1 B2.....B15 .......D15
```

I want the Output as like this

```
A1-10
A2-10
..
..
D15-10
```

In Access it show query is too high.. Please help me to optimize this

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is called 'unpivoting'. Unfortunately there is no way to 'unpivot' information in MS-Access. You are correct that `union all` is the only way to realise this in MS-Access.

You can go different ways from here:

1. you can make the reports with columns (`SELECT * ...`) and copy
   the result to MS-Excel where you can flip the resulting matrix with
   a copy-paste(transpose) action.
2. you can link the MS-Access database to a back-end database that can perform 'unpivot' commands. I do this with MS-SQLserver.
3. you can restructure the input to load in MS_Access in an unpivoted way as in

`Partnumber Version Location    Quantity
1038305320  1   A1  10
1038305320  1   A2  15`

4. Create a view with only the locations, Then select `partnumber` and `version` later when the view is available

   `CREATE VIEW storageLocations as 
      SELECT 'A1' AS Location , A1 AS Qty FROM Inventory UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'A2' AS Location , A2 AS Qty FROM Inventory UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'A3' AS Location , A3 AS Qty FROM Inventory UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'A4' AS Location , A4 AS Qty FROM Inventory UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'A5' AS Location , A5 AS Qty FROM Inventory UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'A6' AS Location , A6 AS Qty FROM Inventory UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'A7' AS Location , A7 AS Qty FROM Inventory UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'A8' AS Location , A8 AS Qty FROM Inventory
   ...`

followed by

```
SELECT * FROM storageLocations WHERE PartNumber='1038305320' AND Version =1
```

but with the number of columns you include in 'UNION ALL' MS-Acces may still complain about the size...

My recommendation would be to go for option 2 or 3 if you can influence the direct environment of MS-Access.